# How to properly insert an item in a Python list and send it over the socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server

I am developing a simple client-server application using Python3. The client sends a 13byte data to server and the server processes it. I have the following data as a list in my Python3 code

```
data_s = ['EPC', 0xFE, 0xED, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08]
```

I am sending this list to a server application on localhost by

```
s.sendall(bytes(str(data_s),"utf-8"))
```

On the server side I receive the data by

```
recv_data = client.recv(64)
recv_data = recv_data.decode()
```

Now I want to verify if the data I received actually contains "EPC" at the start.The problem is that recv_data[0] actually contains '[' instead of "EPC" and recv_data[1] contains ' (single quote) . I have to do

```
if recv_data[2:5] == 'EPC':
```

My question is why is EPC starting at index [2] and not [0]. Any idea how I could actually place EPC at index [0] and 0xFE at index [1] and so on.

Sorry for this lame question I am actually new to Python and been coding mostly with C/C++.

**Server Code**

```
#!usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys
import threading

data = list(list())
client_id = 0
mutex = threading.Lock()


def service_client(client, address):

    global data

    thread_id = threading.get_native_id()
    print("Thread Created for " + address[0] + ', Thread ID: ' + str(thread_id))

    with mutex:
        recv_data = client.recv(64)
        recv_data = recv_data.decode()
        # print(recv_data[2:5])
        if recv_data[2:5] == 'EPC':
            data.append(recv_data)
            data = (list(dict.fromkeys(data)))
            print(data)
            client.sendall(b'ACK ' + bytes(str(thread_id), "utf-8"))
        else:
            client.sendall(b'NACK ' + bytes(str(recv_data), "utf-8"))
        print("Thread ID:" + str(thread_id) + " Finished")


def main():

    global client_id
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 29600

    server_socket = socket.socket()     # TCP socket object

    try:
        server_socket.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as error:
        print(str(error))
        sys.exit()

    print("Waiting for client...")
    server_socket.listen(5)

    try:
        while True:
            client, address = server_socket.accept()  # Accept connection when client connects
            print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
            client_thread = threading.Thread(target=service_client, args=(client, address))
            client_thread.start()
            # client_thread.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt has been caught.")

    finally:
        server_socket.close()
        print("Server socket closed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Exiting Code")
```

**Client Code**

```
#!usr/bin/python

import socket

data_s = ['EPC', 0xFE, 0xED, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08]
host = 'localhost'
port = 29600

#print(data_s[0])

s = socket.socket()     # TCP socket object
s.connect((host,port))


s.sendall(bytes(str(data_s),"utf-8"))

data = s.recv(1024)   

print (data.decode())               # Print received(echoed) data
s.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: try this **if recv_data[1:6] == 'EPC':** or loop through recv_data's elem and do **if elem == 'EPC'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because, when you call `str` on a list like that, the square braces are included:

```
my_list = ['EPC', 'WRT']
my_str = str(my_list)
print(my_str)
```

produces `"['EPC', 'WRT']"`. You are in string land, now, not list land. Hence, calling `my_str[0]` produces the first character in the string, instead of the first element of the list. There are double quotes and square braces present, in fact. One way you could handle this is to strip the square braces and double quotes off, and change back into a list via the `split` function:

```
recv_data = recv_data[2:-2].replace("'", "").replace('"', '').split(',')
```

This should produce a list again, and testing `recv_data[0]` should yield `'EPC'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also could you tell me how to convert a list that contains both string and integers to a byte type object so that I could send it over the socket? 
`
data_s = ['EPC', 0xFE, 0xED, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08]
`

Comment: It is working but I was wondering if this even possible.